# Filter rows based on priority after group by clause in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica

After grouping below table by id I want to filter rows based on condition

Input table :

| ID | Options |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 132 |
| 1 | 156 |
| 1 | 134 |
| 2 | 145 |
| 2 | 132 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 3 | 132 |
| 3 | 135 |
| 3 | 188 |

if a group contains 134 and 132 then only the row with 134 should be filtered. whereas the group contains only 132 then that has to be selected. Rows with options other than below table remain unchanged.

Below are the conditions

| Combination of option in a group | Row with below option value in a group has to be retained |
| --- | --- |
| 132,134 | 134 |
| 132 | 132 |
| 132,135 | 135 |
| 132,136 | 136 |

Output table :

| ID | Options |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 134 |
| 2 | 145 |
| 2 | 132 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 3 | 135 |
| 3 | 188 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are saying that "134" should be the only element when "132" is also in the group.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum( case when options = 132 then 1 else 0 end ) over (partition by id) as num_132,
             sum( case when options = 134 then 1 else 0 end ) over (partition by id) as num_134
      from t
     ) t
where num_132 = 0 or num_134 = 0 or options = 134
```

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. This gives the desired output. But the issue here is its not always necessary that column  num_132 or num_134 exists. Sometimes the option can be 136 instead of 134 or not both. In such case how to specify the column name in the where clause of  outer query?

Comment: @JoyceeCardoza . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, please ask as a *new* question.